# Show only results from table where a certain combination of variables is not present in other table?

Tags: mysql

I want to build a system in which users can submit quiz questions and users can also rate those questions.

There are two tables relevant to my problem:

- "Question", which contains a questionID, a userID(from the user who
  submitted the question), a correct answer, a wrong answer, another
  wrong answer and a boolean that is set to true when the question
  survived the validation process.
- "Validation", which contains a questionID for which question is validated, a UserID for which user validated it and a validation (0,
  1 or 2 depending on the rating the user gave the question).

To give users questions that need rating, I need a MySQL query with which I receive a question that is:

- not through validation yet (validated bool = false)
- not made by the user requesting it
- not already validated by the user requesting it
- the first question in the list of results with these factors

EDIT: I found a solution, look at the bottom edit.

I have tried the following query:

```sql
set @UserId=5;

SELECT q.id, q.question, q.correct_answer, q.wrong_answer1, q.wrong_answer2
FROM question q 
LEFT JOIN validation v ON v.question_id=q.id 
WHERE q.validated = 0 
AND q.user_id!=@UserId 
AND v.user_id!=@UserID 
ORDER BY q.id 
LIMIT 1
```

- I exclude questions already through validation with WHERE q.validated = 0.
- I make sure it's the first question in the list of results with ORDER BY q.id LIMIT 1
- I exclude questions made by the user requesting it with q.user_id!=@UserId

This query returns nothing, though. 
The question table contains some unvalidated questions. The validation table is empty.

I know the mistake lies somewhere within the LEFT JOIN validation v ON v.question_id=q.id and v.user_id!=@UserID parts, but I don't know how to translate my will to MySQL..

EDIT: I found a solution that worked for my problem:

```sql
set @UserId=5;

SELECT q.id, q.question, q.correct_answer, q.wrong_answer1, q.wrong_answer2 FROM question q 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM validation v WHERE v.user_id=@UserID AND q.id = v.question_id) 
AND q.validated = 0 AND q.user_id!=@UserId
```

But, I read this method is very bad for performance. 
Is there a more performant method?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for null in v.user_id because there is no entry.
This query works:

```
set @UserId=5;
SELECT q.id, q.question, q.correct_answer, q.wrong_answer1, q.wrong_answer2
FROM question q 
LEFT JOIN validation v ON v.question_id=q.id 
WHERE q.validated = 0 
AND q.user_id!=@UserId 
AND v.user_id is null or v.user_id!=@UserId
ORDER BY q.id 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the contribution. 
I applied it and it seemed to work at first, but then I realized that this method does not exclude returning questions that have already been validated by a user. What should I change in the query to exclude questions that have already been validated once by a user?

Comment: the query excludes questions with validation = 0. see this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74bf36/9) please update the sqlfiddle with data that is not working

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood me, I wasn't refering to the validation boolean. My post states:
To give users questions that need rating, I need a MySQL query with which I receive a question that is:
- not through validation yet (validated bool = false)
- not made by the user requesting it
- not already validated by the user requesting it
- the first question in the list of results with these factors

Note the third point: "not already validated by the user requesting it". 

The not-so-performant solution I found does this. Your suggestion, however, does not (yet).

Comment: Then I still missunderstand you. Please provide the tables, sample data and the expected results in a sql fiddle and i will help.

Comment: Let's say the user id is 5. 
He gave question with questionid 3 a rating of 2, so the validation table is updated with UserID: 5, QuestionID: 3, Rating: 2.

Now, this question is still not through the validation process, so it's still in the pool of questions that need validation. (validation bool = 0)

Now, when user with user id 5 requests another question to rate, I don't want my query to return a question that has already been rated by him. 
My (not so performant) query does that, yours does not (yet). 

I don't think I can make it more clear than this. So I hope you understand.